# Google App Engine for Spring Boot application always giving java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-cloud-sql

I have a Sprint Boot app with Maven. And I have enabled  MySQL Connector/J ( true) for my application. But after deployment of my app in Google Cloud, I am always getting "Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver'" (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver). Kindly check and advice on this at the earliest.  My code to get connection is as below.

BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();

```
        System.out.println("Inside prod-->");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
            System.out.println("Inside Class.forName-->");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Inside ClassNotFoundException-->");
        }
        System.out.println("after Class.forName-->");
        ds.setDriverClassName(props.getProperty("gcdriverClassName"));
        ds.setUrl(props.getProperty("gcurl"));//System.getProperty("ae-cloudsql.cloudsql-database-url")
        ds.setUsername(props.getProperty("gcusername"));
        ds.setPassword(props.getProperty("gcpassword"));
        ds.setInitialSize(Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("gcinit_pool_size")));
        ds.setMaxActive(Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("gcmax_pool_size")));
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver` class is not automatically available in the App Engine runtime. So you have to enable it by adding `<use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>` element into your `appengine-web.xml` located in `PROJECT_HOME/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` directory.

Please refer "[Using Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#Setting_up)" documentation more details.